# AWS Amplify Identity Broker - Lambda PostDeployment never triggered

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, deployment, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify-cli

I'm currently deploying the [AWS Amplify Identity Broker](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-amplify-identity-broker/tree/master) project but I have an issue with its initialization.

The `PostDeployment` Lambda is never triggered. Even after following Step 9 of the [documentation](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-amplify-identity-broker/blob/master/Documentation/UserDocumentation.md).

`amplify push --force` never triggers this lambda and I honestly never see where it should be triggered.

The `PostDeployment` is supposed to push the `HOSTING_DOMAIN` environment variable to every lambda but as it's never triggered mine don't have it.

The `team-provider-info.json` does have the `hostingDomain` value though :

```
    "amplifyIdentityBrokerPostDeployment": {
      "deploymentBucketName": "amplify-amplifyidentitybroke-lyvoctest-95846-deployment",
      "s3Key": "amplify-builds/amplifyIdentityBrokerPostDeployment-494a576a50636d565154-build.zip",
      "hostingDomain": "https://d1dedba3yfrcyr.cloudfront.net"
    },
```